# Флеш плеер через Awesomium не хочет включать аппаратное ускорение графики

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, awesomium, flash-player

1. В обычных браузерах и даже в WebBrower флеш работает нормально.
2. У WebKit тоже нормально, но там другие не менее приятные проблемы, как и в WebBrower

Тестовый проект. 
https://yadi.sk/d/vNqPoYRQ3J8vuQ

1. Пробовал подсунуть dll'ку с другой версией флеша (19) - не помогло.
2. Пробовал этот код - не помогло.

   ```
   webControl1.ViewType = WebViewType.Window;
   WebPreferences wp = new WebPreferences();
   wp.EnableGPUAcceleration = true;
   wp.WebGL = true;
   WebSession ws = WebCore.CreateWebSession(wp);
   webControl1.WebSession = ws;
   ```

Comment: А для кого это пишется? Может, у них и без аппаратного не будет тормозить, а у вас просто ноут с помойки. Весь мир не осчастливить.

Comment: @Rou1997 На любом компьютере будут тормоза, разве что кроме самых топовых процессоров. Но проблема не только в тормозах, но и в уровне графики. Без аппаратного ускорения она упрощенная.

Comment: Сидите и тупо пробуйте разные движки, если с каким-то вообще ничего не получается - локализуйтесь на эту проблему и тот же подход к ее решению. Если получится хоть что-то и флеш тормозить не будет - на остальные мелочи закрывайте глаза. Так и сделаете хоть ЧТО-ТО. В конкретно же данном случае, проверьте работают ли вообще ваши настройки которые задаете, а то не уверен, я через WebSessionProvider делаю.

Comment: Тестовый проект не нужен - мы не подорвемся делать вашу работу за вас, не глядя что вы новичок и что все печально. У нас своей печали черти накачали :)

Comment: Хорошо) просто я думал может там все просто и банально, и это только я не догоняю. Кстати щас вот нарыл какую-то инфу, что в движках хромиум какое-то там "усиление безопасности среды выполнения Adobe Flash Player" и какое-то PPAPI надо включить, и вообще с Flash Player версии выше 11.4 могут быть проблемы.... попробую все это сделать, и dll флеша 11.3 подкинуть.

Comment: @Rou1997, не согласен. Тестовый проект в большинстве случаев полезен.